# React input onChange issue using Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a simple cryptocurrency app just to check the prices and some info using Coingecko API
In my react app  I´ve decided to use a global context to manage the coin data, fetched using axios from Coingecko API,Also i´ve implemented a search input where the users can type a name to filter the data in the table,the problem with this SearchBar component is that as soon as I initialize the app on the browser nothing is shown in the table, I have to perform a change on the input to start showing the data
My code is the following

Starting with Coins Context:

**CoinsState.js**

```
import { React, useReducer } from "react";
import coinsReducer from "./CoinsReducer";
import coinsContext from "./CoinsContext";
import axios from "axios";

export default function CoinsState(props) {
const initialState = {
 coins: [],
};
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(coinsReducer, initialState);

const getData = async () => {
const res = await axios.get(
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false"
);

  dispatch({
    type: "GET_COINS",
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
return (
  <coinsContext.Provider
    value={{
      coins: state.coins,
      getData,
    }}
  >
    {props.children}
   </coinsContext.Provider>
 );
```

}

**CoinsContext.js**

```
import { createContext } from "react";  
const coinsContext = createContext()
export default coinsContext
```

**types.js** used in CoinsReducer.js

```
export const GET_COINS = "GET_COINS";
```

**CoinsReducer.js**

```
import { GET_COINS, } from "../types";


 export default (state, action) => {
 const { payload, type } = action;

 switch (type) {
   case GET_COINS:
     return {
       ...state,
       coins: payload,
     };

   default:
     return state;
 }
```

};

Now my react components

**SearchBar.js**

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import coinsContext from "./context/Coins/CoinsContext";
export default function SearchBar({ handleFilterCoins }) {
 const { coins } = useContext(coinsContext);
 const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
   handleFilterCoins(coins, search);
 }, [search]);

 const handleOnChange = (e) => {
   setSearch(e.target.value);
 };
 return (
   <input
     type="text"
    placeholder="Start typing to get results"
    className="form-control bg-dark text-light border-0 mt-4 text-center w-100 "
    autoFocus
     value={search}
     onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
   />
 );
```

}

**TableCoin.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import coinsContext from "./context/Coins/CoinsContext";
import CoinRow from "./CoinRow";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
const TableCoins = () => {
 const { coins, getData } = useContext(coinsContext);

 useEffect(() => {
   getData();
 }, []);

 const [filteredCoins, setfilteredCoins] = useState(coins);

 const titles = ["#", "Coin", "Price", "Price Change", "24hs Volume"];

 const handleFilterCoins = (coins, filter) => {
   setfilteredCoins(
     coins.filter((coin) =>
       coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
     )
   );
 };
 return (
   <div className="container">
    <SearchBar handleFilterCoins={handleFilterCoins}></SearchBar>
     <table className="table table-dark mt-4 table-hover ">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {titles.map((title) => (
            <td>{title}</td>
           ))}
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        {filteredCoins.map((coin, index) => (
           <CoinRow coin={coin} key={coin.id} index={index + 1}></CoinRow>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
 );
};

export default TableCoins;
```

**CoinRow.js**

```
import React from "react";

const CoinRow = (props) => {
  const { coin, index } = props;
  return (
   <tr>
     <td>{index}</td>

     <td className="fs-3">
       <span>
         <img
           src={coin.image}
           alt={coin.name}
           style={{ width: "15%" }}
           className="me-3 img-fluid"
         />
       </span>
       {coin.name}
       <span className="ms-3 text-muted text-uppercase fs-4">
         {coin.symbol}
       </span>
     </td>

    <td>{coin.current_price}</td>
     <td
       className={coin.price_change_24h > 0 ? "text-success" : "text-danger"}
     >
       {coin.price_change_24h}
     </td>
    <td>{coin.total_volume}</td>
   </tr>
 );
```

};

```
export default CoinRow;
```

finally **App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import CoinsState from "./components/context/Coins/CoinsState";
import TableCoins from "./components/TableCoins";
function App() {

  return (
    <CoinsState>
       <div className=" row ">
         <TableCoins></TableCoins>
       </div>
    </CoinsState>
  );
}

 export default App;
```

I dont really get what is going on with this issue, i´ve tried to manage the filteredCoins as parte of the global Coins context but it ends up in the same result, the coins data not showing as soon as the app starts, but it does after performing an update on the SearchBar

However this isn´t an issue if I treat the SearchBar insdie the App.js as a normal html input managing its value with a state and passing the search input as a prop to TableCoins

**App.js**

```
 import "./App.css";
 import { useState } from "react";
 import CoinsState from "./components/context/Coins/CoinsState";
 import TableCoins from "./components/TableCoins";
 function App() {
 const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

 return (
   <CoinsState>
     <div className="container">
     <input
           type="text"
           placeholder="Search a Coin"
           className="form-control bg-dark text-light border-0 mt-4 text-center w-100 "
           autoFocus
          onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
         />
       <div className=" row ">
         <TableCoins search={search}></TableCoins>
       </div>
     </div>
   </CoinsState>
 );
```

}

export default App;

**TableCoins.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import coinsContext from "./context/Coins/CoinsContext";
import CoinRow from "./CoinRow";

const TableCoins = ({ search }) => {
 const { getData, coins } = useContext(coinsContext);

 useEffect(() => {
   getData();
   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

 const titles = ["#", "Coin", "Price", "Price Change", "24hs Volume"];

  const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin) =>
  coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
 );
  return (
  <table className="table table-dark mt-4 table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {titles.map((title) => (
        <td>{title}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {filteredCoins.map((coin, index) => (
      <CoinRow coin={coin} key={coin.id} index={index + 1}></CoinRow>
    ))}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

);
};

```
 export default TableCoins;
```

I think it has something to do with the way useState hook works asynchronously,but if you could shed some light over this I would be thankful

Comment: This is a lot of code, can you narrow it down to just the parts that you think are relevant for the issue?

Comment: I think the issue is in **Searchbar.js** specially in the callback function handleFilterCoins inside useEffect, probably it also has something to do with **CoinsState.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution to this issue.
I gave another opportunity to the Context approach to solve this problem

Inside `CoinState.js` I´ve set 2 more fields on the state

```
const initialState = {
    coins: [],
    filteredCoins: [],
    filter: '',
};
```

`filter` is used to track the actual input of the user and `filteredCoins` saves the result of the filtering process

```
const filterCoins = (search) => {
    const result = state.coins.filter((coin) =>
        coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    );
    dispatch({
        type: "SET_FILTERED_COINS",
        payload: result,
    });
};

const setFilter = (filter) => {
    dispatch({
        type: "SET_FILTER",
        payload: filter,
    });
};
```

`SET_FILTERED_COINS` and `SET_FILTER` are types defined in `types.js` with their  own reducer to manipulate the context state

Now, inside `SearchBar.js`, this context is consumed, using the `UseEffect` hook we can track the filter value and trigger the filtering process each time it changes.

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import coinsContext from './context/Coins/CoinsContext';

const SearchBar = () => {
    const {setFilter, filter, filterCoins} = useContext(coinsContext)
    useEffect(() => {
        filterCoins(filter)
    }, [filter]);
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search a Coin"
            className="form-control bg-dark text-light border-0 mt-4 text- 
center w-100 "
            autoFocus
            onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
        />
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```